# The symmetry of green's function in a Dirichlet problem

Tags: greens-function, greens-theorem

Consider the Green's problem $$\Delta G(x,y|s,t)=\delta(x-s)\delta(y-t)\ \ on\ \ R\\ G=0 \ \ on \ \  \partial R $$
Check if $G(x,y|s,t)=G(s,t|x,y)?$

Can not we say that since the differential operator is self adjoint, $G$ is symmetric? Or it depends on the location of $s,t$ if it is in $R$, on $\partial R$, or outside $R \cup \partial R.$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you really mean to write $\Delta^{2}$?

Comment: Oh no it is the Laplacian, thanks Ali.

Comment: Sounds plausible but wouldn't you have to demonstrate self-adjointness in some Hilbert space that includes the deltas? I hope someone who knows more about this stuff will chime in.